# sql- server 2008 full features are not appearing

Tags: sql-server

I have installed sql server 2008 which installed successfully.
but when I goes to start menu only following features are appearing:
1-)sql server configuration manager
2-) send errors and reports
3-)sql server installation center

But other features like "Enterprise manager", "query analyzer" are not appearing. I want to use sql server as a stand alone installation with its full features just like as sql server 2000. 
I want to create databases using enterprise manager as well as using query analyzer and also want to make reports. But I could not find these features in the list in start menu.

Then some one told me to install "sql server 2008 management studio", which i did, but i don't know that how to access enterprise manager, query analyzer, and  reporting services in management studio?

Please guide me.

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server did you install? Where did you get it?

Comment: Also, Enterprise Manager has been replaced with SQL Server Management Studio, which also contains the query analyzer. It actually took me a second to make that connection, as it's been forever since I worked with SQL Server 2000. You can also use SSMS to connect to SSRS, though if you want to develop a report in SSRS, you'd have to use Data Tools (I think it's called data tools for SQL 2008). 

Why are you on 2008? Why not straight away skip to 2012 or 2014?

Comment: Enterprise Manager and Query Analyzer are Sql 2000 components, which had been replaced by management studio since 2005. You need to use management studio to create, manage, and query database, and use Sql Server profiler for performance track.

Comment: Yes you are saying right. I installed SQL Management studio and all is set. Thanks ScmitzIT and cqi.